# UIImage generated base64 is larger than it's referenced (local) base64 image

Tags: swift, base64

I am capturing an image via a user's Camera (using a library called CameraManager). The captured image is saved to the file disk (for testing purposes only), and also generates a UIImage, which is then converted to a base64 string via:

```
cameraManager.capturePictureWithCompletion({ (image, error) -> Void in

let UIImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.85)!
let base64Image = UIImage.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
...
```

Now when I select the same image (which was saved to the disk) via an image-picker plugin, I am returned a base64 string (of the same image) and it is a little more than 2.5x smaller than the original captured image that it represents.

What could be causing the extra overhead? Could it be something that is being embedded in the UIImage? My other thought was to just save the UIImage to a temp folder, pass the URI to the client, and then have the client worry about converting it to a base64 string to see if it makes the string smaller.

Comment: You are decreasing image size here `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.85)!`
 try `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 1)!`

Comment: Yes, but the captured image that I am decreasing in size, is almost 2.5x larger than the version that is saved in the camera library when comparing the base64 strings.

Answer (score 0):

Using the current `CameraManager` library and having the same issue, I ended up writing the `Data` with jpeg extension instead of the `UIImage`. This gives the same size as what saved in Camera library.

```swift
cameraManager.capturePictureWithCompletion({ result in
    switch result {
    case .failure: break
    case .success(let content):
        ImageStoreService.store(image: content.asData!,
                                forKey: createFileName(),
                                withStorageType: .fileSystem)
    }
})
```

Comment: Could you please post a link to CameraManager library?

Comment: In addition to linking to the library, it would be helpful to others if you were to post the test case(s) you developed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).